# Unique character code not working when ran in linux but fine in windows (C++)

Tags: c++, linux

When I run the code in windows, it works as expected.  But when I run it in linux, the program doesn't run as expected and produces a completely different output.

I'm assuming its a problem in the all_unique_letters method, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: *"it works as expected"* - We have no idea, what **you** expect. Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/37532873/edit) your question and add both the expected behavior and observed behavior.

Comment: Maybe it goes out of numeric type range? On my 64-bit Mac, it works fine... Maybe [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/37532873/edit) your question and precise what is exactly the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `bool all_unique_letters(const string &s)`, `unsigned int v;` is used without being initialized. If it contains something else that `0`, the function reports a letter as a duplicate when it is not.

Comment: Yes. (I think this is even reported by some compilers, but I don't remember which one)

Comment: That depends on the warning level set during compiling.